# c++: casting a parent class to a subclass and calling a subclass's function

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a parent class called A, and a subclass called B.
B has method printB();

Why can I c-style cast an A pointer to a B pointer and access method printB()? even though A doesn't have a printB() func?

```
class A {
    
};

class B: public A {
    public:
    void printB() {
        std::cout<<"testB"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a; 
    A* aPtr; 
    B b; 
    B* bPtr;
    
    aPtr = &a;
    ((B*)aPtr)->printB();
    
    return 0;
}
```

main prints: testB

Comment: Undefined behavior. There must a be a duplicate somewhere, but I am too lazy, at the moment, to look for it.

Comment: C style casts don't do any compile time or runtime validation. This is why C++ has additional `dynamic_cast` and others.

Comment: C++ never stops you from inventing new ways to write broken code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance; you get the same behaviour if you declare `a` as `int` and then cast it to `B`.

Comment: To prove @CostiCiudatu's point: [UB example](https://godbolt.org/z/de5jhq)

Comment: You know how people lie, and then other people believe them and behave as if those lies were true? It's that.

Comment: @crashmstr alright I understand, thanks!